# Committing a docker container after build fail

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, containers, devops

I'm trying to use the Docker plugin in Jenkins to commit a docker container when the build running on it fails. Currently I have a Jenkins server with ~15 nodes, each with its own docker cloud. The nodes all have the latest version of docker-ce installed. I have a build set up to run on a docker container. What I want to do is commit the container when the build fails. Below are the things I have tried:

- Adding a post build task, where I obtain the container ID and the hostname of the node running the container. I then SSH into the node and then commit the container.

  - The problem: Not able to SSH from inside a container as it requires a password and there's no way adding the node to the container's list of known hosts
- Checking the "commit container" box in the build's general configurations

  - The problem: This is probably working but I don't know where the container is being committed to. Also this happens every time, and not just when the build fails.
- Using the build script

  - Same problem as using the post build task
- Execute a docker command (Build step)

  - This option asks for the container ID, which I have no way of knowing as it is new every time a build is run.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood any of the above ways! I am still new to Jenkins and Docker so I am learning as I go. :)

Comment: Manually `docker commit`ting is usually not a best practice.  You might try translating the sequence of steps Jenkins does into a Dockerfile, and commit that to source control, if your goal is to get a Docker image out.